# sqlite group-by with sort-by-desc does not work as expected

Tags: sqlite

I have a aggregate query properly indexed to return ordered results fast (simple index scan). This works as expected when ordering is ascending (ASC), but reversing the order (DESC) results in sqlite creating a TEMP B-TREE

sqlite version 3.26.0

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1(x,y);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2,1);
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON t1(x,y);

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT x,max(y) FROM t1 GROUP BY x ORDER BY x;
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT x,max(y) FROM t1 GROUP BY x ORDER BY x DESC; -- This query constructs a TEMP B-TREE, why?
```

When running above code you will see query 1 simply running a index scan, while query 2 in addition to running a index scan, also makes a TEMP B-TREE to order the result, destroying performance.

The index created supports traversing both direction so I would expect same performance for both ASC and DESC ordering.

Is this a known limitation in sqlite and aggregates, or am I expecting/doing something wrong?

Comment: FWIW, Dr Hipp considers it a bug if you are getting the wrong result. Otherwise it's _just_ a missed optimization opportunity, not a _bug_. I think he has a point :)

Comment: Yes, I agree, will refrase last sentence

Comment: Try implementing a custom collation with reversed comparison order.  The index would then be constructed in "ASC order", but the actual collation function will handle the reversal, thereby eliminating the TEMP B-TREE step.  Disclaimer:  I didn't test this. Also, depending on the host language, the custom-collation function may introduce it's own deficiency.

Comment: Thanks, that may work but I need to be able to order ASC/DESC dynamically, with good performance either way. Currently I'm trying to add a window function to trick the queryplanner to use corret loop-direction, but no sucess so far

Comment: If you need such good performance with "dynamic" order, perhaps you should consider an in-memory structure.  Is the data set reasonable to hold it all in memory?  Is it really necessary to requery the database?  If the size or other requirements demands direct database query, perhaps you could implement your own optimization by creating a second table or column with a different sort.  Triggers or other code could be used to synchronize both versions of the data.  In other words, offset the expense on the insert so that alternative select queries can be optimized.

Comment: Both ASC and DESC order is important. The table is approx 500k rows today but the logic using this type of query only looks at top/bottom N records. When hitting the index, the results are instant, when missing the index, the result is delayed by several seconds. A in-memory version will not differ very much from a warm on-disk version.

Current version use triggers and multiple indexes to accomplish what I want, but this is very complex and slow. Using a indexed group-by query will accomplish the same with better performance if it would only work.

Answer (score 1):

The code for looping over an index goes backwards only when needed. For implementing GROUP BY itself, going backwards is never needed, so it is never tried.

In reaction to your report on the sqlite-users mailing list, SQLite version 3.30.0 [will have code](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/20f7951bb238ddc0) to handle this case:

```
    /* The GROUP BY processing doesn't care whether rows are delivered in
    ** ASC or DESC order - only that each group is returned contiguously.
    ** So set the ASC/DESC flags in the GROUP BY to match those in the 
    ** ORDER BY to maximize the chances of rows being delivered in an 
    ** order that makes the ORDER BY redundant.  */
```

Comment: This optimization seems trivial compared to other advanced optimizations in sqlite, I'm a bit surpised (and sad) that I run into this issue that is effectivly blocking my project. You don't have any suggesting for tricking sqlite into trying traversing group_by in reverse direction?

Comment: Already tried some variations of DESC in index, same result as before. Declerative descriptions are nice until you hit some annoying thing that the fancy optimizer don't handle very well. If only I had a bit more control over the query-planner